# Toolbar in listview item cause list selector is disable

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with custom item like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the listview

```
  <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvProfile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/list_line"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

And adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // use viewholder etc..
   viewHolder.toolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_profile_item);
   objHolder.toolBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {


            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Everything is fine except the background selector item not work. Although I use `android:listSelector` or use default, nothing happened. The problem is when I remove the toolbar from list item (or make its visibility is gone), the selector works well. I have no idea why this can happen. Is there any idea?

**Update**: my problem is solved by use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in root item listview

Comment: Why would you put a toolbar in a list view item? Are you trying to emulate the popupmenu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you are looking for is called a `PopupMenu`:**

Please take a look at the following example. You will need to create a `Button` for your `PopupMenu` in your `ListView` item's XML. In this example, they are using `onCreate()` in an `Activity`.

```
  private Button btnFilter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Locate filter button and attach click listener
    btnFilter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFilter);
    btnFilter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFilterPopup(v);
        }
    });
    // ...
  }
```

**Show the `PopupMenu`:**

When you click on the `Button` in the `ListView` the `PopupMenu` is displayed:

```
  private void showFilterPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    // Inflate the menu from xml
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_filter, popup.getMenu());
    // Setup menu item selection
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_keyword:
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Keyword!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            case R.id.menu_popularity:
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Popularity!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            default:
              return false;
            }
        }
    });
    // Handle dismissal with: popup.setOnDismissListener(...);
    // Show the menu
    popup.show();
  }
```

**Menu XML:**

Example menu that will be inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_keyword"
          android:title="Keyword" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_popularity"
          android:title="Popularity" />
</menu>
```

### Here is another Example from Cabinet Beta:

**The "`PopupMenu` in the `Adapter`":

```
    PopupMenu mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    mPopupMenu.inflate(file.isDirectory() ? R.menu.dir_options : R.menu.file_options);
    boolean foundInCopyCab = false;
    boolean foundInCutCab = false;
    DrawerActivity act = (DrawerActivity) mContext;
    if (act.getCab() instanceof CopyCab) {
        foundInCopyCab = ((BaseFileCab) act.getCab()).containsFile(file);
    } else if (act.getCab() instanceof CutCab) {
        foundInCutCab = ((BaseFileCab) act.getCab()).containsFile(file);
    }
    mPopupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.copy).setVisible(!foundInCopyCab);
    mPopupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.cut).setVisible(!foundInCutCab);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        mPopupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.pin).setVisible(!Pins.contains(mContext, new Pins.Item(file)));
    } else {
        MenuItem zip = mPopupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.zip);
        if (!file.isRemote()) {
            zip.setVisible(true);
            if (file.getExtension().equals("zip"))
                zip.setTitle(R.string.unzip);
            else zip.setTitle(R.string.zip);
        } else zip.setVisible(false);
    }
    mPopupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            mMenuListener.onMenuItemClick(mFiles.get(index), menuItem);
            return true;
        }
    });
    mPopupMenu.show();
```

https://github.com/kshark27/cabinet/blob/6763d6bdf6471da98e2d8ae1a4d60ed4e3a6dbe2/app/src/main/java/com/afollestad/cabinet/adapters/FileAdapter.java

**The "`PopupMenu` XML"**:

https://github.com/kshark27/cabinet/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/list_item_file.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:src="?overflow"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="?menu_selector"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp" />
```

#### Here is a picture of Google Play utilizing the `PopupMenu`:

[image: PopupMenu on GooglePlay]

Source: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Menus-and-Popups#popup-menu
Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html

Comment: well, I know this one. Actually it can work as toolbar,  but my problem is the toolbar is hook up click event on list view item, so I use android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" for the root item, and it work well. The same behavior for popup menu when I use a button or imageview in list item to show menu. So, the question is, why should I use popup menu instead of toolbar in this case?

Comment: Why would you inflate an entire *ActionBar/Toolbar* for *EVERY* `ListView` row? That's a waste of resources.

Comment: well, I use view holder pattern, so I don't inflate for every row (just get toolbar view inflate when convert view is null).  But you're right, the popup menu may be the right way because tool bar is designed to replace action bar.

Comment: View holder pattern inflates when the view is null. I understand what you are trying to say. Let me know if you need any more help with this. Those Github links will have the "overflow" icon you will need.

Answer (score 0):

put android:focusable="false" in the xml entry of list item like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```